# Login item stored on SMB share causes Warning when not connected to the network

Tags: macos, applescript

I wrote an Apple Script that mounts all of our company network shares and saved it as a .app to a general network folder that all users can read. I then added the file to the login items on my test mac. When I am connected to the network, the script runs fine. 
The problem is, when the computer is off the network (simulating the user bringing the laptop home), after you log in, the system obviously cannot find the file any more and prompts the user "there was a problem connecting to ...".
I know the obvious answer is to store it locally on the system but I want to be able to manage this file and make changes as needed.
Is there a way to suppress this warning?

Comment: At least, you need local script to determine if offline or online. and that script must be stored on your computer locally. but that script could be very simple and if online, then it runs your main script stored on shared drive.

Comment: I Agree, that was the conclusion I was coming to.
I tried to run this:
'try
open smb://ip.address/share/file.app
end try'
but I still come back with errors.

Comment: I assume that you must checked that the shared volume is online. then once it is online, it gets a volume name. You can see this volume name in Terminal using command "ls /Volumes" (inside a do shell script!). if the volume is in the list, then, you're online and you can use Finder pass to open your second script (the one on the server) with: try open "volume_name:folder_path:file.app" end try. This should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a bit more tests, and here is script and method for you :

1) mount your share drive, and , in Terminal, type "ls " (don't forget space) and drop your file.app. you do not need to hit return, this is just to get right path. you should see something like "/Volumes/drive_name/Path_folder/File.app" (Drive_name and Path_Folder values will depend of your share drive structure).

2) remove the "/Volumes/" part at beginning of that path. change the "/" by ":" and store the new "finder path" in the first line of script bellow : (take care is you have spaces, because Unix has replaced them by "\ ". please also replaces them back to standard spaces.

make the script bellow (the 1 line contains your new path)

```
set Finder_Path to "drive_name/Path_folder/File.app"

tell application "Finder" to set OnLine to (Finder_Path exists)
if OnLine then
try
    do shell script "osascript " & (POSIX path of Finder_Path)
end try
else
display dialog "sorry, you're off line"
end if
```

This script checks first that Finder can access to the file (= the drive in mount !). if it can, then it runs the file.app. if no, then it displays message.
I tested ok replacing file.app by application made with Applescript.